# Ember.js can't get data from another models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new with Ember and I need help to understand how to show data with multiple models.
I'm using fixture adapter and there my models and fixtures

**User model**

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    phone: DS.attr(),
    comment: DS.attr(),
    city: DS.belongsTo('city'),
    type: DS.belongsTo('type')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Roger Brown',
    phone: '+1 (218) 12345678',
    comment: 'Lorem ispum dolor sit amet in voluptate fugiat nulla pariatur.',
    city: 3,
    type: 1
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ashton Black',
    phone: '+7 (920) 12345678',
    comment: 'Lorem ispum dolor sit amet in voluptate fugiat nulla pariatur.',
    city: 4,
    type: 2
}
];
```

**City model**

```
App.City = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    user: DS.hasMany('user', {async: true})
});

App.City.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Lisbon',
        user: [1]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Moscow',
        user: [2]
    }
];
```

**Type model**

```
App.Type = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    user: DS.hasMany('user', {async: true})
});

App.Type.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'individual',
        user: [1]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'legal entity',
        user: [2]
    }
];
```

**My user route**

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    }
});
```

**User template**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="panel form-horizontal">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title">User View</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p>{{name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p>{{phone}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p>{{comment}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p>
                    {{city}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p>{{type}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button {{action 'deleteUser'}}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

And when I trying to show user detail I get something like that

```
City <App.City:ember385:3>
Type <App.Type:ember388:1>
```

Please help to understand how to get name of this fields!
Thank you very much :smile:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `City` and `Type` objects are Ember types-  you would need to display the properties you are interested in, like this:

```
{{city.name}}
{{type.name}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Also I added 
`{async: true}` 
to my user model and that works perfectly ^^